# Angular - <div _ngcontent-c0> is not inheriting the parent div width

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, angular5

I am building `ASP.Net MVC` application with `Angular 5` & here is template looks like.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Home Page - My ASP.NET Application</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
 <base href="/" />

 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container body-content">

  <div class="col-md-12">
    <app-root>test</app-root>
  </div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <footer>
    <p>&copy; 2018 - Foodie</p>
 </footer>
 <link href="/Assets/bundles/styles.59e253c87b78feb8a0f7.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="/Assets/bundles/inline.318b50c57b4eba3d437b.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="/Assets/bundles/polyfills.515ed9df1f4876ab6cb6.bundle.js"></script>
```

```
</body>
</html>
```

This is how the screen is rendering.

[image]

I have no clue the dynamic placeholder `<div _ngcontent-c0>`generated by Angular is taking with of 412px

While if you see I have `col-md-12` on the parent div & this is causing layout issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `app.component.scss` use the following:

```
:host {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yes. this addressed my requirement.. Great Thanksssssssssssssssss :)

Comment: Can you please help explain why i need to do this? Its not very frequest that i should have to keep doing this on each element i create. I'm a little confused as to why this is peculiar

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the class "container" use "container-fluid". Similarly for row css class, then use row-fluid. 
Note : .container has one fixed width for each screen size in bootstrap (xs,sm,md,lg); .container-fluid expands to fill the available width